# Grouping rows with similar names and retaining their unique values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame called "`data`" in R as follows:

```
Name  Values
    A A01;B87;C23
    A A01;D45
    A A01
    B U98
    C P08;M23;K98
    C P89;D23
C G65;H76;D23
```

I would like to group the rows with same `Names` and retain only unique `Values`  like following

```
A A01;B87;C23;D45
B U98
C P08;M23;K98;P89;D23;G65;H76
```

I tried the following code using "aggregate" function but it yielded an output far(pasted below) from my expectation

```
>aggregate(data$Values~data$Name,FUN=unique)
sam$Name sam$Values
1        A    2, 3, 1
2        B          7
3        C    5, 6, 4
```

Kindly guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: Before you apply `aggregate` do `data$Values <- as.character(data$Values)`

Answer (score 2):

After converting the my `data$Values` into a character and then applying aggregate function, it worked.